# Comparing two very long string, got the error : 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#

I coded a program for comparing two very long string(10 000 000) in C#.

the code is like this:

```
// sample strings for you:
string test1 = new string('A',100000000), test2 =new string('A',100000000);
int i = 0, interval = 100000, size = test1.Length;
if (test1.Length != test2.Length)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    while(i + interval < size){
    if (test1.Substring(i, i + interval) == test2.Substring(i, i + interval))
    {
          //TO DO          
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    i += interval;
}
```

While, it occurs the error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when i = 5 400 000.

Why it happens?

Comment: Side note: Please to try to provide smallest necessary sample that is showing problem... In your case it would be 1 line: `new string('A',100000000).Substring(5400000, 5 500 000);`. I understand that it may remove need to ask question in a first place, but you not going to gain reputation on questions with large blocks of code anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this line:

```
if (test1.Substring(i, i + interval) == test2.Substring(i, i + interval))
```

The second argument for `String.Substring` is, [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **length** (System.Int32): *The number of characters in the substring.*

You are **using** it as the 'last index to retrieve'. According to those same docs, an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown if:

```
startIndex plus length indicates a position not within this instance.
 -or-
startIndex or length is less than zero.
```

Halfway through, you are retrieving `Substring(test1.length / 2, (test1.length / 2) + interval)`, making the first condition true, once you get about halfway through the string, which conforms to the 5.4 million mark you mention for a 10+ million character string.

---

Management summary: you shouldn't add `i` to the second parameter of the `Substring` calls.

Comment: If I do add i to the second parameter of substring, how I compare the two strings?

Comment: Might be time to evaluate the reason why you need to compare such a large string in the first place, and whether such an approach is the best one.

Comment: @cindywmiao I don't understand the followup question. By adding `i` to it you're using the parameter wrong, causing the overflow. It's just not what you intend to do, and your code will work fine if you remove it (bar the fundamental bug that you're not processing the last fractional part of the string).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, sorry I misunderstands before. It's ok now.Thank you a lot.